# Smartedit TypeError: Cannot read property 'siteId' of undefined

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

When starting SmartEdit in Hybris, calling a site and click on "Basic Edit" or any else edit functionality, it shows following error:

```
defaults.js:19 TypeError: Cannot read property 'siteId' of undefined
    at cmssmarteditContainer.js:1
    at defaults.js:19
    at m.$digest (defaults.js:19)
    at b.$apply (defaults.js:19)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (defaults.js:19)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (thirdparties.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.q.handle (thirdparties.js:3)
```

Anyone here knows how to solve this?

Best Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

We had this issue aswell and fixed it by adding missing SmartEdit JS files to the page master template.

Missing JS files causing the problem:

```
webApplicationInjector.js
reprocessPage.js
adjustComponentRenderingToSE.js
```

After adding them, SmartEdit was able to edit the page and the problem didn't occure anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exactly same problem. I found out that SmarteditaddonCmsPageBeforeViewHandler was being added to a before view handdler list that I am not using. I edited my spring-mvc-config and added it to defaultBeforeViewHanddlerList. I did the same thing for SmarteditaddonBeforeViewHandlerListMergeDirective. It's working for me now